# error while running solr index

Tags: solr, hadoop, nutch

I am running solrindex on nutch crawled data using the following command:

```
bin/nutch solrindex <prep><code>http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ /app/hadoop/tmp/crawled_pages/crawldb -linkdb /app/hadoop/tmp/crawled_pages/linkdb /app/hadoop/tmp/crawled_pages/segments/*
```

I am getting the below error and I am not able to root cause for this issue.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=http://www.bbc.co.uk/portugueseafrica/arquivo/index.shtml] unknown field 'cache'

ERROR: [doc=http://www.bbc.co.uk/portugueseafrica/arquivo/index.shtml] unknown field 'cache'

request: <prep><code>http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.write(SolrWriter.java:124)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:55)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:497)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:195)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:519)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
2012-12-10 10:05:49,198 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

Did anybody got similar problem?

I don't understand what is the root cause for this below error..

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=http://www.bbc.co.uk/portugueseafrica/arquivo/index.shtml] unknown field 'cache'
```

Comment: where's that 'cache' field? it looks like the problem is in your schemma, please check

Comment: when I look at http://www.bbc.co.uk/portugueseafrica/arquivo/index.shtml page, there is  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> in html code. other than this, I did not have any clue.

Comment: do you mean schema.xml in solr configuration?

Comment: yes, it looks like your xml schemma doesn't have the field 'cache'

Comment: ok. thank you. I check and let you know.

Comment: thanks a lot :) it worked. I will try to find out what it signifies.

Comment: @Swamy can you tell me the file name and location in which you have added 'cache' field. I have added 'cache' field in solr-X.X.X/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml and solr-X.X.X/example/solr/conf/schema.xml but I am still getting the same error. Thanks

Comment: @zahid Added the following line in solr_xx_xx/example/solr/conf/schema.xml     "<field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following line in solr_xx_xx/example/solr/conf/schema.xml

```
<field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: I am not getting anymore and I dont want to disturb the system. I removed the error by remving all references of cache field in nutch conf folder.